# Xamarin Component BindableProperty not initializing properly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom Xamarin Forms component with a `Required` property that I am setting to `True` in my viewmodel. In the constructor, I call a method `CheckValidity()` which checks whether the entry is required. For some reason, `Required` is showing up as false until I type in the entry (triggering the `Text` property to update) or click in or out of the entry (triggering the `Unfocused` event).

Any idea why the initial `True` value of `Required` is not taking effect until some activity occurs in my component? Thanks!

**Use in View**

`<ui:ValidatingEntry Text="{Binding MyText}" Required="True" />`

**Component XAML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyPackage.ValidatingEntry">
     <ContentView.Content>
         <StackLayout x:Name="entryContainer">

             <Entry x:Name="entry" />

             <Label x:Name="message" />
         </StackLayout>
     </ContentView.Content>
 </ContentView>
```

**Component C#**

```
public partial class ValidatingEntry : ContentView
{
    private enum ValidationErrorType
    {
        NONE,
        REQUIRED,
        CUSTOM
    }

    private ValidationErrorType validationErrorType;

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ValidatingEntry), default(string), BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);

            Debug.WriteLine("set text to: " + value);

            CheckValidity();
            UpdateMessage();
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty RequiredProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Required", typeof(bool), typeof(ValidatingEntry), false);

    public bool Required
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("getting required property: " + (bool)GetValue(RequiredProperty));
            return (bool)GetValue(RequiredProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(RequiredProperty, value);

            //THIS NEVER PRINTS
            Debug.WriteLine("set required property to: " + value);

            CheckValidity();
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(ValidatingEntry), true, BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsValidProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(IsValidProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void CheckValidity()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("checking validity");
        Debug.WriteLine("required? " + Required); //prints False until Entry is unfocused or user types in Entry
        Debug.WriteLine("string empty? " + string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text));

        if (Required && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("required but not provided");
            IsValid = false;
            validationErrorType = ValidationErrorType.REQUIRED;
        }
        else
        {
            IsValid = true;
            validationErrorType = ValidationErrorType.NONE;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateMessage()
    {
        switch (validationErrorType)
        {
            case ValidationErrorType.NONE:
                message.Text = "";
                break;
            case ValidationErrorType.REQUIRED:
                message.Text = "This field is required.";
                break;
        }
    }

    public ValidatingEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("Text", source: this));

        CheckValidity(); //at this point, Required is always false

        entry.Unfocused += (sender, e) =>
        {
            CheckValidity();
            UpdateMessage();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `CheckValidity()` in an eventhandler that is raised after the constructor is done, like `BindingContextChanged`:

```
public ValidatingEntry()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    BindingContextChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        CheckValidity();
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the missing piece of the puzzle! Working perfectly now with no need to add an arbitrary delay. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Properties of a type will not be updated with values from XAML until the constructor for the type returns, so you want to run `CheckValidity` after the constructor returns.

The easiest and quickest way to do this would be to launch a background thread to run `CheckValidity` as this will allow the constructor method to return and populate the properties with the values set in XAML. So try this:

```
public ValidatingEntry()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("Text", source: this));

    Task.Run(() => { 
        CheckValidity();
        UpdateMessage();
    });

    entry.Unfocused += (sender, e) =>
    {
        CheckValidity();
        UpdateMessage();
    };
}
```

It is worth noting that this is not exclusive to Forms. In a default (parameterless) constructor, only properties that have default values set will be already set when the constructor is running. So if you want the default to be `true`, set the default value in your `BindableProperty.Create(...)` method call for the `Required` property, e.g.:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty RequiredProperty = 
              BindableProperty.Create(
                  "Required", 
                  typeof(bool), 
                  typeof(ValidatingEntry), 
                  true);
```

As an example, one might think that when you do this:

```
 var x = new MyType { MyString = "New text" };
```

That `MyString` will be set in the constructor, but that is not true. The above is syntactic sugar that gets changed at compile time to the equivalent of:

```
 var x = new MyType();
 x.MyString = "New text";
```

So the constructor completes, and then the property is set.

However if you have a default value, e.g.:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string MyString { get; set; } = "Default text";
}
```

`MyString` will be set to "Default text" and available in the constructor.

An example Console app to demonstrate:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var x = new MyType { MyString = "New text" };

        var y = Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MyType
{
    public MyType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Constructor: {MyString}");
        Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine($"Task: {MyString}"));

    }

    public string MyString { get; set; } = "Default text";
}
```

output will be:

> Constructor: Default text
>
> Task: New text

Comment: Wow - thank you for the incredibly detailed and helpful answer! I tried putting `CheckValidity()` in a `Task.Run()` to run on a background thread as you suggested, and it still didn't work, but I added `await Task.Delay(1000)` before the call to `CheckValidity()` and it now seems to work properly. 

Any idea why I needed the additional delay? I verified the background thread ran after the constructor finished, but maybe my new background thread was still running before the code to set XAML bindings?

Comment: Yes, there could be a potential race condition since there is no guarantee as to when the Task will execute. It may execute very quickly, perhaps before the properties get set. How long you need depends on how much work has to be done setting the properties for the type. What may be best is to run the CheckConfiguration and UpdateMessage code from the OnAppearing method of the page that is using the custom view.